# How i get Ubuntu 18.04 server ISO file

Tags: 18.04

I all ready downloaded ISO(ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso) file, but when am i going to install the Ubuntu 18.04, after finishing installation process, it's come with Desktop Version.

I don't know what happen, i downloaded file three times but i get same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of iso files with Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS,

- The new style iso file with the live installer, size 806 MiB,

  [releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/](http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/)
- The old style iso file with the debian installer, size 704 MiB,

  [cdimages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/bionic/release/](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/bionic/release/)

You can try both and use the one that works best for you.

Comment: @SinghRavi, You are welcome. Good luck with your server :-)